# Generalised solution for Mat-select width

Tags: javascript, css, angular, user-interface, angular-material

By default, the width of mat-select is not equal to that of the input (or mat-form-field). Is there a generalized solution to make them of equal width? Attaching a screenshot of what I want to achieve.

[image]

This can be achieved by giving a width of 250px to the mat-form-field and a min-width and transform property to the mat-select but this would not be a general scenario to fill all the cases in the application. Any clue on how to go about it?

Comment: So, is it like this by default? https://nimb.ws/pd8znP

Comment: Yes it is like that from default

Comment: You could add the mentioned CSS in your global `css` file

Comment: I think its not required, because what if drop-down list has more data to display then width of dropdown becomes more than of what you had declared previously. Let be it default.. Let me know if you have any other point to say. @AshishKumar

Comment: I understand your point @GaurangDhorda but the design requires it to be like this.When the data is more it would made ellipsis anyway

Comment: Equal width of both.. Can you explain it more?